# Why does the cursor not show in input fields for Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, keyboard, focus

I have several html input fields on my web form. When I tab back and forth the field that has focus does not show the blinking cursor when using Internet Explorer, but does when using Chrome, Safari or Firefox.
The text fields initially show watermark text when not in focus.

I have spent days Googling the answer for this but to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this issue on IE9 (did not reproduce in IE10+, and didn't test below 9). The problem occurred when the form was within an element being translated with `-ms-transform`. Removing the transform fixed the issue.

Comment: I am having the same issue, transform is causing to lose the cursor, anyone knows why?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that this is common behavior of the IE, as a workaround first try to add `cursor: text` to the input(s), then if did not worked you may try to set the cursor style using javascript on focus event.

Actually, microsoft themselves do this as in the http://login.live.com form.

Hope this helps ...

Answer (score 1):

Try calling focus() and select() via javascript when you want the cursor to be shown in IE on an input having the watermark (placeholder) set.